# Undefined Key and empty value in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, local-storage

I have an HTML signup form which takes input and stores in JavaScript array then use `JSON.stringify` and finally stores it on local storage. The problem is that the key is `undefined` (email is my key) and the value is `[object Object]`. Can anybody help me solve this issue? Thank you?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="usrDetails" onclick="return false">
        <h1>sign up</h1>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/><!--the name attribute describes input name and is used as reference.-->
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/><!--placeholder defines the text to appear in the blank box-->
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Retype Password"/>
        <input type="submit" onclick="storeUser();"/> <!--value defines the text to appear on the button-->
    </form>

    <p id="result"></p>

    <script>
        function storeUser() {
            var usrObject={};
            if (document.getElementById("username") !== null) {
                usrObject.username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("email") !== null) {
                usrObject.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('password') !== null) {
               usrObject.password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('password2') !== null) {
                usrObject.password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
            }
            localStorage.setItem(usrObject.email, usrObject) 
            JSON.stringify(usrObject);
            //localStorage[usrObject.email] = JSON.stringify(usrObject);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<b>Registration successful</b>"
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Javascript has nothing to do with Java. They only share a part of the name.

Comment: If I've learnt anything from using StackOverflow, it's that people need to start learning to use console.log() more.

Comment: how can I modify my code to store usrObject? I tried to use setItem but it did not work. I must have wrongly used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `document.getElementById()`, but you have no IDs on your inputs. Your form should be:

```
<form id="usrDetails" onclick="return false">
    <h1>sign up</h1>
    <input type="text" id="Username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/><!--the name attribute describes input name and is used as reference.-->
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/><!--placeholder defines the text to appear in the blank box-->
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Retype Password"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="storeUser();"/> 
</form>
```

Also, the line:

```
localStorage[usrObject.email] = JSON.stringify(usrObject);
```

Should be:

```
localStorage.setItem(usrObject.email, JSON.stringify(usrObject));
```

...assuming you want the email address to be the key of the stored user object.